# Last revision Chromium Embedded Framework 3

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2, chromium, chromium-embedded

Where can I find the latest revision of the Chromium Embedded Framework 3 for Delphi? I downloaded it from this page with TortoiseSVN:

http://code.google.com/p/dcef3/

because CEF1 gave too many problems, but it is a very old revision, there is a download of the revision 24, but the latest revision is 823. Could you tell me where to find the latest version for Delphi-XE2?

Thank you very much.

Comment: how do you know the last revision is 823? from [history](http://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/list), it looks like r24 is the last one.

Comment: On this page there are all revisions of CEF1: 

http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/list

but in this page, there is a download revision 302: 

http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/downloads/list

why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three projects that have been mentioned here:

- [chromiumembedded](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/), latest revision 996
- [delphichromiumembedded](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/), latest revision 147
- [dcef3](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3), latest revision 24

These are three distinct projects. You cannot compare revision numbers across projects. That's an apples and oranges comparison. You compare revision 24 of dcef3 with revision 823 of some other project. That comparison is simply meaningless.

I suspect that some of the confusion is because the dcef3 and delphichromiumembedded projects depend upon chromiumembedded. So you may see, in the dcef3 and delphichromiumembedded projects, mentions of chromiumembedded revision numbers. This is indeed confusing and you need to keep a clear head when navigating these projects.

The project that you are interested in is dcef3. And so you should use the latest revision which is, as of today, revision 24.

I have to say that this is a marvellous project. It's incredible that we can pull down this code from an svn repo, build the source immediately, and in less than a minute have a functioning Chromium web browser inside a VCL form, from which I can edit this very post. Bravo!

Comment: I certainly concur for the **`Bravo!`**

Comment: If only this project would continue... quoting Henri, "I no longer work for free on Delphi projects."

Answer (score 5):

The latest revision of the [Delphi Chromium Embedded 3 project](http://code.google.com/p/dcef3/) is available from the project's Google Code Subversion repository. The project's [source check-out page](http://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/checkout) has instructions on the command-line way of getting the source code, while the project home page has instructions on using TortoiseSVN. As of right now, that's [r24](http://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/detail?r=24), from November 2012.

That project is based on the [Delphi Chromium Embedded project](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/), where the latest revision is [r147](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/detail?r=147), from July 2012. The downloads for that project mention revision numbers higher than that. They're not revision numbers for that project, though. Instead, they're revision numbers for the [Chromium Embedded Framework project](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/), where the most recent revision is yesterday's [r996](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/source/detail?r=996). The downloads available from the Delphi project are binaries from [CEF's r306](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/source/detail?r=306), *not* binaries of the Delphi project itself; you're expected to compile the Delphi code yourself.

Comment: @GiacomoKingPatermo No, that conclusion is incorrect. The latest version of delphichromiumembedded is 147.

Comment: There is no such project as "CEF1." There are three projects involved here, and r306 is not the latest revision of *any* of them. There are two Delphi projects, and neither of them has 306 revisions. There's also the C++ project, which in the time since I posted my answer earlier today has acquired 8 more revisions, bringing the total over 1000. The original *Delphi* project is distributing *binaries* built from revision 306 of the *C++* project. The second Delphi project (dcef3) has no binaries available.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is a VCS behind (SUbversion) you can grab the latest source/revision from `trunk`

[SVN trunk](http://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/#svn/trunk%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

And Revision 24 is not very old (Nov 20, 2012)