# Delphi Chromium Embedded - version of Chromium?

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm using Delphi Chromium Embedded Framework release 3.06 (the last one, I guess...)
What version of Chromium is involved in this release ?
And is there possibility to update Chromium itself ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you figure you have version 3.06 of [Delphi Chromium Embedded](https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/). That project doesn't have version numbers.

Maybe you're looking at [the binary downloads it last updated in October 2011](https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount), which are from revision 306 of the [main Chromium Embedded Framework project](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). As of today, the latest revision of CEF is [r1617](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/source/detail?r=1617); r306 is comparatively ancient.

Use [DCEF3](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/). It's an entirely separate project from Delphi Chromium Embedded. According to the [DCEF3 commit history](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/list), the latest Chromium Embedded Framework release it supports is 3.1547.1412, which corresponds to Chromium 29.0.1547.59, and which you can [download from cefbuilds.com](http://cefbuilds.com/#branch_1547). That's DCEF3 revision [e319b4a6fbe2](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/detail?r=e319b4a6fbe21adfd9df75ce4d73cfbfd3b6956f).

You need to read your project names and revision numbers carefully.

Comment: For reference, another question where these three projects were confusing: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14364425/33732